# How do I DISPLAY on multiple lines?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to display the current time every second, but the current time shows up on only 1 row and it seems to delete the last result.

I tried doing it like this, but this only sets the width and height for the box that contains the information.

```
DISPLAY currentDate + currentTime FORMAT "x(50)" WITH 5 DOWN 5 col.
```

Here's what I would like:

[image]

Comment: Somewhat larger code snippets would go a long ways towards making answers to your questions more helpful.  In this case you have omitted whatever looping mechanism you have -- which is probably the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I really appreciate it. I'll try to add more code to my future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do while true:
  display now with 5 down.
  pause.
  down.
end.
```

The DOWN command forces the frame to move to the next iteration.  Whether or not you need it depends on the nature of the block that the frame is scoped to.  (DO blocks need it.)